# О bootstrap адаптивные блоки

Tags: bootstrap

Может кто нибудь знает, как сделать адаптивность на фиксированный размер блока например [вот страница](http://tajmarket.ru/catalog/otc-1/otc-109) когда уменьшить размер экрана, размер блока увеличится а надо чтобы размер блока остался фиксированным а при уменьшения просто перемещался вниз, [как здесь](http://shoppica.net/clothing)

Comment: если я правильно понял, надо после <h2 class="title text-center"> поменять классы колонок с `col-md-3` на `col-xs-3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, кроме `col-md-3` стоит ещё добавить `col-sm-4` и `col-xs-6`?
На сайте по второй ссылке блоки всё-таки изменяют размер, только там в зависимости от размера чаще меняется количество ячеек в строке.